# count function in php from phpmyadmin database not working

Tags: php, mysql

Having an issue with getting the code working. It does not seem to be working. I have other codes which work fine which use query string etc... e.g. I used a query string to display the results in the table and that worked fine.

```
$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `tbl_response`";
$result3 = queryDatabase($queryString);
while($stat = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
  echo $stat
}
```

Comment: `echo $stat` won't work.  `$stat` is not a string, it's an array.

Comment: Try `echo $stat[0];` see what that produces. Or `$var[] = $stat[0]; echo $var;` in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$stat` is an array not a string, you need to use `print_r` or else `echo $stat[0]` inside your loop.

Having said that, you're only going to get one row (and one field) returned, so there's an easier way to do this. No loops required:

```
$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `tbl_response`";
$result3 = queryDatabase($queryString);
echo mysql_result($result3,0);
```

Side note: you need to migrate to `mysqli` or `PDO`, you are using deprecated `mysql` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL syntax seems off. You have it set as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_response`;
```

But I would set a name as `count` to actually easily access the data like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM  `tbl_response`;
```

I’m also unclear as to what your larger PHP framework is to run the query, but the way I would write this out in straight PHP is:

```
$queryString = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM  `tbl_response`");
$result3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryString);
echo $result3['count'];
```

And yes, those are using outdated `myql_` calls, so this is essentially the same but with `mysqli_` instead:

```
$queryString = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM  `tbl_response`");
$result3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryString);
echo $result3['count'];
```

Comment: The OP does have what you wrote in the first line of code: `$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  `tbl_response`";`

Comment: Yes I agree Jake, I noticed your edit. I think it read as "It should be..." as your opening sentence. Just a mixup ;-)

Comment: hi, thanks very much ! it worked perfectly. I'm also trying to get another one.. which works however only shows the name of the table. $queryString = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl_response'"; but if I use this in phpmyAdmin.. it gives all sorts of info like number of rows, engine, version,Create_time, update_time. how can i get this to show on my page? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as number_of_responses FROM  `tbl_response`";
$result3 = queryDatabase($queryString);
while($stat = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
  echo $stat['number_of_responses'];
}
```